# define a class in many class php

Tags: php, class

I need to define a class in many classes and i should use all of this class in one class ! And `$this` dosn't work on this way .

> Undefined variable

```
class main extends Controller{
    //some codes
}
```

In another file

```
class site{

    function test(){
                include main.php;
                $obj = new main();

        class first{

            function name(){
                $obj->somefunction();
            }

        }


        class second{

            function family(){
                $obj->somefunction();
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you rearrange your classes/functions to ensure that **main.php** is only included once?

Comment: No it's more than one include because classes aren't at one page @CharlieJoynt

Answer (score 0):

First of all, class declaration cannot be nested: You can't declare a class within a class, nor within a function.

As per your second question, if you want to have different classes with the same name, you should use namespacing to differentiate them.

Also, you should follow the PSR coding style convention (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Have a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thanks for your help , i see. i am doing a wrong method but i can't solve my problem with your reference :(

Comment: you question is a bit too broad for an exact answer. What do you want to do exactly? you say you want do define a class in many classes but it is not possible. You should spend some time reading the PHP documentation of follow an online course on Object Oriented programming.